# Problema al añadir Bootstrap a angular 11

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, bootstrap-4, scss

Mas adelante quiero modificar el css de Bootstrap mediante scss por eso necesito hacerlo de esta forma.

Buenas quiero integrar Bootstrap a mi proyecto de angular 11 pero este no lo detecta, instale boostrap jquerry y popper con el siguiente comando:

mas adelante quiero modificar el css de Bootstrap mediante scss.

```
npm install bootstrap jquery @popperjs/core
```

y añadí este código a angular.json

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_moydules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Se supone que es así como se integra boostrap, pero este no funciona, este código lo tengo en el app.component para comprobar que esta importado bootstrap

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Prueba</button>
```

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona? Te sale error? No muestra los estilos?

Comment: Seguro que pusiste la referencia a bootrstrap donde debías? A mi me ha pasado que a veces "no sirve" porque lo puse en la sección de production, en lugar de la de development

Comment: @JuanRivera no muestra ningún error,  solamente al poner las clases de bootstrap no se carga su css

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán tenias razón no me di cuenta . Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

si vas a integrar unicamente minimizado `.min` no tiene caso instalarlo, puedes agregarlo directamente al archivo `src/index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        ....
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        ....
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mas adelante en el proyecto quiero modificar el Bootstrap con scss, así que necesito importarlo así..